# R: Dummy coding using mutate, ifelse and grepl - Error

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm attempting to dummy code two levels of three in a variable (in two steps) as I want to run a regression. I'm very new to R and have not written the code myself.

Step 1: The variable is Birth_order and the two levels I'd like to analyse are Firstborn and Later born, while excluding only children from the analysis (and dummy coding).

```
Dat <- mutate(Dat, Wth_Sib= ifelse(grepl("Firstborn", Dat$Birth_Order), 1, 
       ifelse(grepl("Later born", Dat$Birth_Order), 0, NA)))
```

Running the code it gives me the error of:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Wth_Sib` must be length 212 (the number of rows) or one, not 0
```

Step 2: Comparing siblings vs. only children.

```
Dat <- mutate(Dat, Sib_vs_Only= ifelse(grepl("Firstborn", Dat$Birth_Order), 1, 
       ifelse(grepl("Later born", Dat$Birth_Order), 1, 0)))
```

Error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Sib_vs_Only` must be length 212 (the number of rows) or one, not 0
```

I don't know what the error means and I'm somewhat unsure of if the code is the best way of approaching the task. I've looked everywhere for answers and I'd be so grateful for any help or advice on a better method!

Thanks!

Comment: It means that `ifelse(grepl("Firstborn", Dat$Birth_Order)` returns NULL, check out your code and see why is that happening

Comment: In general, you don't need to code dummy variables manually for regression in R. Simply filter out only children & run the regression on your data frame. R will treat one of the levels in your categorical level as the reference & take care of the rest. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33871122/categorical-variables-in-r-which-one-does-r-pick-as-reference